# Inverse function of numpy as_strided

Tags: python, numpy, stride

I have a 4-tensor `x`. The 6-tensor `y` is computed as follows:

```
x = np.random.randn(64, 28, 28, 1)
strided_shape = 64, 26, 26, 3, 3, 1
y = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, strided_shape, strides=(x.strides[0], x.strides[1], x.strides[2], x.strides[1], x.strides[2], x.strides[3]))
```

`strided_shape` in general can be any shape as long as the first and last dimensions match those of `x` (this is just a concrete example).

My question is, using `y` (and the `x.shape` and `x.strides` tuples), is it possible to recover the original tensor `x`, using `as_strided` again, `reshape`, `sum`, etc.? Note: I am not actually planning on applying said process to `y` itself; rather I want to perform the procedure on a tensor with the same shape as `y`.

Comment: `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is quite risky, would it be enough to use `np.reshape` and/or `np.tile` ? There it would be maybe easier to recover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `y` is simply a view into `x`, with different shape and strides. As such, recovering `x` from `y` is simply changing back the shape and strides. So, given those (assuming those are saved before the `x` to `y` conversion), it would be simply -

```
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(y, x.shape, x.strides)
```