# How to implement col2im() in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

`im2col` has already been efficiently implemented in python with code like:

```
def im2col_sliding_strided(A, BSZ, stepsize=1):
    # Parameters
    m,n = A.shape
    s0, s1 = A.strides
    nrows = m-BSZ[0]+1
    ncols = n-BSZ[1]+1
    shp = BSZ[0],BSZ[1],nrows,ncols
    strd = s0,s1,s0,s1

    out_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=shp, strides=strd)
    return out_view.reshape(BSZ[0]*BSZ[1],-1)[:,::stepsize]
```

which is comes from the [Implement MATLAB's im2col 'sliding' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109068/implement-matlabs-im2col-sliding-in-python)

But it doesn't have solution for the column to image back.
Is there any method to speed it up?

Comment: If the result is a `view`, there's  no need to convert back. Any in-place changes to the view will appear in A`.

Comment: @prune, I don't see this as off-topic. It's based on an earlier SO, and a common speedup 'trick', `as_strided`

Comment: @hpaulj I've read things over twice, thanks to your note.  It's now borderline in my mind -- which is plenty of doubt about my original position.  I'm withdrawing my objections.  Thanks.

Comment: I just tested this.  The `as_strided` does create a view, but the final `reshape` has to make a copy.  So the result is not a `view`.

Comment: I was thinking of a simpler `as_strided` case where @Divakar pointed out that it's just a view: [inverse function of numpy as strided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447526/inverse-function-of-numpy-as-strided)